# Android ArrayList didn't list out all the elements in TextView

Tags: android, arraylist

I am learning `ArrayList` in Android and i have an error for my scenario:

```
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("SuperMan");
    list.add("BatMan");
    list.add("Xman");
    list.add("WhatEverMan");

    TextView omg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    for(String item:list){
        omg.setText("You are "+item+" ");

    }
```

I try to change to this also not working

```
omg.setText("You are "+item.toString()+" ");
```

**It only display "WhatEverMan" in the `TextView`.**

And another question is that what's the difference between

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

**I run these 2, both didn't prompt any errors, just that it only display "WhatEverMan"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
TextView omg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
for(String item:list){
    omg.setText(omg.getText().toString()+item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
String text = null;
for(String item:list){
   text += (" " + item);
}
omg.setText(text);
```

`ArrayList<String>()` and `ArrayList<>()` is the same in your situation

Comment: when I run your coding, there is a "Null" infront

Answer (score 1):

You will get last value, because every-time value will rewrite into `TextView`

so you can use `StringBuilder` or you have to append text.

**example**

`omg.append(item);`

Answer (score 1):

setText() sets the final text in ArrayList while in loop. Better make String variable and append on them. then set the text.

```
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("SuperMan");
    list.add("BatMan");
    list.add("Xman");
    list.add("WhatEverMan");

    TextView omg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String s = "";
    for(String item:list){
        s+=item+"\n";
    }
    omg.setText(s);``
}
```